# How do I stop pybind11 from deallocating an object constructed from Python?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

So, I know that pybind lets you [set a return value policy](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/functions.html) for methods that you wrap up. However, that doesn't seem to be working for me when I try to use this policy on a constructor. I have a class to wrap my C++ type that looks like this:

```
class PyComponent{
public:


    static Component* Create(ComponentType type) {
        Component* c = new Component(type);
        // Irrelevant stuff removed here
        return c;
    }

    /// @brief Wrap a behavior for Python
    static void PyInitialize(py::module_& m);

};
```

```
void PyComponent::PyInitialize(py::module_ & m)
{
    py::class_<Component>(m, "Component")
        .def(py::init<>(&PyComponent::Create), py::return_value_policy::reference)
        ;
}
```

However, this does NOT stop my Component type from getting deallocated from the Python side if I call `Component()` and the created object goes out of scope. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I did figure out the solution to this. It's to pass `py::nodelete` to the wrapper for my class

```
void PyComponent::PyInitialize(py::module_ & m)
{
    py::class_<Component, std::unique_ptr<Component, py::nodelete>>(m, "Component")
        .def(py::init<>(&PyComponent::Create), py::return_value_policy::reference)
        ;
}
```